# CSS hierarchy DIV

Tags: css

I am developing a easy forum system, and it is using the hierarchy data from the database.

I would like to make something similar to the following site,

http://protocolexchange.community.invitrogen.com/thread/1003?tstart=5

Any idea what I need to to make the DIV display in "Tree" order?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/tVBfQ/2/)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `margin-left` in your style rule for the `<div>`s.